# Iterate on (or access directly) xarray chunks

Tags: dask, python-xarray

I'm after a way to iterate on `xarray` chunks, so something similar to `dask.array.blocks` but that would give me access to xarray chunks with coordinates and dimensions.

For the record, I'm aware that `xarray.map_blocks` exists, but what I'm doing maps input chunks to output chunks of unknown shape, so I'd like to write something custom by looping directly on the xarray chunks.

I've tried to look into the `xarray.map_blocks` source code, since I guess something similar to what I need is in there, but I had a hard time understanding what's going on there.

EDIT:

My use case is that I would like, for each xarray chunk, to get an output xarray chunk of variable length along a new dimension (called `foo` below), and eventually concatenate them along `foo`.

This is a mocked scenario that should at least clarify what I'm after.
For now I've solved the problem constructing, from each dask chunk of the DataArray, an "xarray" chunk (but this looks quite convoluted), and then using `client.map(fn_on_chunk, xarray_chunks)`.

```py
n = 1000
x_raster = y_raster = np.arange(n)
time = np.arange(10)
vals_raster = np.arange(n*n*10).reshape(n, n, 10)
da_raster = xr.DataArray(vals_raster, coords={"y": y_raster, "x": x_raster, 'time':time})
da_raster = da_raster.chunk(dict(x=100, y=100))

def fn_on_chunk(da_chunk):

    # Tried to replicate the fact that I can't know in advance 
    # the lenght of one dimension of the output
    len_range =  np.random.randint(10)
    outs = []
    
    for foo in range(len_range):
        # Do some magic that finds needed coordinates
        # on this particular chunk
        x_chunk, y_chunk = fn_magic(foo)
        out = da_chunk.sel(x=x_chunk, y=y_chunk)
        out['foo'] = foo
        outs.append(out)
    
    return xr.concat(outs, dim='foo')
```

Comment: just to clarify - `xr.map_blocks` applies a function in parallel to all blocks. you're specifically looking for a way to iterate through the blocks one at a time? this seems to defeat the purpose of using dask... can you provide more detail about your expectations and use case? e.g. would you still like to use dask to execute in parallel, but you'd like the result to be a list of #blocks chunked DataArrays of varying shape? a practical example, ideally a full [mre] at least setting up the problem, would be helpful, too, just to make sure we're headed in the right direction

Comment: I've added extra information and some code that should clarify what I'm after,

Comment: can you include `fn_magic`? is there anything wrong with that implementation? what you're describing is exactly what I would do. there's no function in xarray currently to iterate over chunks, so it sounds like you have the right approach.

Comment: `fn_magic` is mostly there to build a real-ish scenario, but the actual problem I'm dealing with is much more complex than that, and I think copy-pasting all the relevant code here would just create a mess.

I think the bottom line here is that `xarray` does not provide the equivalent of `dask.array.blocks` (and no easy workaround), which is what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently. You can use the `chunks` attribute like this

```
iy, ix, it = da_raster.chunk({'y':10,'x':10,'time':2}).chunks

idx = [sum(ix[:i]) for i in range(len(ix)+1)]
idy = [sum(iy[:i]) for i in range(len(iy)+1)]
idt = [sum(it[:i]) for i in range(len(it)+1)]
```

you can then subset with

```
tgt_t = xr.DataArray(np.arange(idt[0], idt[1]), dims="time")
tgt_x = xr.DataArray(np.arange(idx[0], idx[1]), dims="xpoints")
tgt_y = xr.DataArray(np.arange(idy[0], idy[1]), dims="ypoints")
da = da_raster.isel(y=tgt_y, x=tgt_x, time=tgt_t)
```

Enumerating on the indices of `idt`, `idx` & `idy` could provide you with the functionality you want in your function.